# AngularJS route stuck while loading data

Tags: ajax, angularjs, get, routes

Im working on an application who use Angular route service.

I also make a lot of $http get request to load a lot of datas in the background of my application.

But while the data is loading I can't change route I need to wait all data to be loaded to change my route.

Is there any way to prioritize the route request to change pages and still load data in background?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to wrap each $http call in timeout, something like:

`$timeout(function() {
              $http.get('test.json').success(function() {
              });
          }, 0);`

Comment: Sorry but It's worked because when I added $timeout the parameter of my query was always the same and it's worked after I fixed this it's still stuck my application maybe it's on my nodejs server side...

Comment: another workaround is use web worker. Or you can throttle how many $http calls each time using libraries such as async io.